# Closing resultset and prepared statment connections for Spring datasource object

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, spring-orm

I am very new for spring F/w. I am using spring jdbc and spring ORM  in my application as persistance layer. I have a doubt like, In a method which calls multiple times, do we need to close the result-set object and statement object. 
Sample code is:

```
public   void  savedata() throws Throwable
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        try 
            {
            int lastUpdated= jdbcTemplate.queryForInt("select serial_id from serial_details ");
        SerialUpdated=jdbcTemplate.queryForInt("select count(* ) from serial_usg  where serial_bill is null  " +
                    " and SURROGATE_KEY > "+lastUpdated);

            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            String Query = "select * from serial_mst where serial_bill is null  and " +
                    "SURROGATE_KEY  > "+ lastUpdated ;
            PreparedStatement pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(Query);          
            ResultSet rs = pStatement.executeQuery();       
            while(rs.next()){
                String data     = rs.getString("serial_bill");                          
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(connection != null && !connection.isClosed()){
                connection.close();
                connection = null;
            }           
        }
```

My Question is, If i call this method multiple times, then do i need to close statement and result-set methods or only connection object is enough to close.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with ONLY closing the connection and not the result set, is that if your connection management code is using connection pooling, the `connection.close()` would just put the connection back in the pool. Additionally, some database have a cursor resource on the server that will not be freed properly unless it is explicitly closed.

Here is a utility method that can be used from a finally block:

```
public static void closeEverything(ResultSet rs, Statement stmt,
        Connection con) {
    if (rs != null) {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
    if (stmt != null) {
        try {
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
    if (con != null) {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource

Comment: @Alexezio Can you add a reference to this piece of information please? "that if your connection management code is using connection pooling, the connection.close() would just put the connection back in the pool."